# PHP Pathing issues

Tags: php

I'm a bit confused, so any answer that you can come up with that will help me get started to look where the problem is will help.

I have /folder1/API.php using: require_once('../folder2/Core.php');

I then have /folder1/Panel.php using: require_once('folder2/Core.php'); (note that there is no '..').

Somehow, both API.php and Panel.php are able to locate Core.php even though they are in the same folder but different require_once parameters.

Even weirder: in /folder2/Core.php, there's require_once('../folder3/DBConfig.php'); in which API.php is able to go through, but when calling a function from Panel.php, it says that I cannot find '../folder3/DBConfig.php'.

Comment: check if there is a folder2 inside folder1..!!

Comment: Are you using Panel.php and API.php alone or are one or both of them included by another script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require (and include) will search in your include path too, perhaps the folders are included there.

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include() will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include() construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require(), which will emit a fatal error.
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that .. say `index.php` includes a file `test.php` which is in another folder.

`test.php` has some includes with relative paths to other files.

Since `test.php` is included in `index.php`, all the relative paths in it will be computed relative to `index.php` (so most will be broken)

---

1 more thing:

`Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include() /and likewise require/ will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.`

Comment: I understand that, but i had two files that are in the same directory locating the same file, but had different paths for each.